# Loading jQuery in the Correct order

Tags: development, javascript, jquery, master-page

I wish to use a jQuery plugin in SharePoint. Currentley I have jQuery added to each page via a custom master page.

```
<script src="/Style Library/js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This can be found in the head section of the page.

I have created a web part. This web part needs jQuery to run. I add jQuery again and the requried plugin as below:

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            Control control = Page.LoadControl(_ascxPath);
            Controls.Add(control);
            ScriptLink.Register(Page, "/_Layouts/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js", false);
            ScriptLink.Register(Page, "/_Layouts/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js", false);
        }
```

The masterpage jQuery is being loaded after the web part. This is causing the plugin not work. If I remove the `ScriptLink.Register(Page, "/_Layouts/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js", false);` I get jQuery us not defined.

If I remove jQuery from my master page it all works.

How can I get the jQuery in the masterpage to load before any other scripts being added to the page?

**Updated**
I have updated the code to be as follows:

```
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        Control control = Page.LoadControl(_ascxPath);
        Controls.Add(control);
    }
```

and

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPreRender(e);
            ScriptLink.Register(Page, "/_Layouts/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js", false);
            ScriptLink.Register(Page, "/_Layouts/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js", false);
        }
```

Both are loaded on the page as can be seen by IE Dev Tool Bar.

[image]

The problem still seems that the master page jquery is loaded after as the same error is occuring. `Removing ScriptLink.Register(Page, "/_Layouts/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js", false);` I get told that jQuery is not valid. It however can be seen in IE Dev Tool Bar.

Comment: Side note: You should consider packaging JQuery in a distinct feature, instead of including it directly in masterpage and/or in every webpart that requires it. See spjquery.codeplex.com (disclosure: Self-promotion). It can handle different versions on different sites. Added bonus: Giving the delegate control a very low sequence number will ensure it is loaded first.

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Why do you add another reference of jQuery when there already is a jQuery reference in the masterpage?

Comment: If the masterpage is changed the feature will keep working. Like what @Louuis said it may be worth putting this in a feature and making this feature depend on that and making the feature that deploys my masterpage depend on it too.

Comment: I have to  ask the same question as Dandroid.  That is most likely the reason why your code is not working.  You cannot have two calls to a javascript library.

Answer (score 3):

ScriptLink only loads the script once, so I see no problem in not adding jQuery in the master page.

But, you could also have ScriptLink in master page and there should not be any conflict:

```
<SharePointWebControls:ScriptLink runat="server" Name="somefolder/jquery-min.js" Localizable="false"/>
```

By the way, did you notice you have different versions of jQuery in masterpage and in the web part?

Comment: Yeah I did notice that. We are upgradding to the 1.7.1.min.js version. The latest master page has not been push to the test enviroment yet.

Comment: Just make sure you're not registering different versions. It will probably create a black hole or something. ;)

Comment: What reference do you need in the masterpage to use SharePointWebControls:ScriptLink?

Comment: <%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePointWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

Answer (score 1):

I think that better solution is to load script later in your webpart. Take a look at this article on MSDN:

[Creating a Web Part with Client-side Script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms948916.aspx)

So put script registration in [WebPart.OnPreRender Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.webpart.onprerender.aspx)

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreRender(e);
    ScriptLink.Register(Page, "/_Layouts/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js", false);
}
```

**UPDATED**

I think problem is that your script function that uses jQuery fires before jQuery and/or plugin is loaded. Try to use something like

```
 ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(jsFunctionWithjQueryPlugin, "jquery.dataTables.min.js");
```

Also avoid double jQuery loads (see @JussiPalo comment on black holes :) and ensure

Comment: Sadly the same things happen

Comment: When your page loads can you check if jquery and jquery.dataTables scripts are loaded or not (with Firefox FireBug or IE developer toolbar)?

Comment: Question updated

Comment: @John - little update on my side also although I am just guessing :/

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to call the JS library a second time if you have it in your master page.  I would update the JS library version to the 1.7.1.min.js and you will never have to reference it.  For your plugins, in my opinion, it is best to stay out of the 12 hive.  Look at my link here on stackoverflow [Adding JavaScript, CSS and others to a WebPart using WSPBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426421/adding-javascript-css-and-others-to-a-webpart-using-wspbuilder/6708260#6708260).

I explain a much better way to load your JS, and css files to keep them inside of your dll instead of loading them into the 12 hive.

Answer (score 0):

First, it is a bad practice to load jQuery twice. The second time you might erase functions from other scripts that already built plugins on top of jQuery.

In your Web Part, instead of loading jQuery you should load a script that will first check if jQuery exists, then load it if the answer is no.

Second, you need to make sure that jQuery is loaded before you use it. I am afraid ScriptLink does parallel loading (not sure here), so you'll need to use a different method: either sequential load, or functions like ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded or requireJS to make it work.

For the record, jQuery has a NoConflict mode that can be useful if you need to deal with different versions of jQuery on the same page (which is probably the case if you combine custom Master Pages and third party Web Parts).